# Maven package open a file (as a *File*) inside a jar package

Tags: file, maven-2, jar, maven

I need to open a file which is inside a maven jar package. It a model configuration for a framework I use and a constructor of a library class requires to pass a object of type *File*. I can get a path to a configuration file using class loader without any problems. But -- unfortunately -- *File* can not read a file inside jar. So I get *java.io.FileNotFoundException*. Now I looking for a solution for this problem. My plan is to decompress the model configuration file and place it in a temporary directory. However, before starting coding, I would like to learn if there is any other solution for such a problem like mine.

UPDATE: I need to read a file in runtime.

Comment: Do you need the file extracted/read from the JAR file at build time or runtime?  You have two great answers below, but both accomplish the task at different points in the development and runtime processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use [JarInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html), traversing through JAR entries one by one, until you find what you need. Then just `read()` content of the found `JarEntry`.

Comment: That won't help if the library needs a File

Comment: Well, you can `read()` from JAR and save to a temporary `File`. Even in this case it's more effective than unpack JAR into a project.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, it lets me to solve my problem. I have used ClassLoader to find a file (a path within a jar file), unpacked it into a temporary directory, and open it as a *FILE*.

Answer (score 4):

If you're doing it from a maven build, unpack the jar resource to a file using

- [`dependency:unpack-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html) (if the jar is one of the project's maven dependenies)

  ```
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <includeGroupIds>the.groupId</includeGroupIds>
        <includeArtifactIds>the.artifactId</includeArtifactIds>
        <includes>**/path/to/your/resource.txt</includes>
        <outputDirectory>where/do/you/want/it</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
   </executions>
  </plugin>
  ```

or use

- [`dependency:unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) (if the jar is no dependency, but still available as a maven artifact)

  ```
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>unpack</id>
       <phase>generate-resources</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>unpack</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
         <artifactItems>
           <artifactItem>
             <groupId>the.groupid</groupId>
             <artifactId>the.artifactid</artifactId>
             <version>the.version</version>
             <type>jar</type>
             <outputDirectory>where/do/you/want/it</outputDirectory>
             <includes>**/path/to/your/resource.txt</includes>
           </artifactItem>
         </artifactItems>
       </configuration>
     </execution>
   </executions>
  </plugin>
  ```